# What are valid publications to put on a grad school application resume?

Tags: publications, application, cv

I am in the process of applying for MS in CS and saw that an academic CV is pretty long and detailed (not like the business ones max. 1-2 pages). Apparently it is common to list all publications. However, I am wondering what counts as a valid publication?

I have a section Publications (peer-reviewed) and one Publications (non-peer reviewed). Is it valid to state publications which exist, but are not publicly downloadable (e.g. confidentiality)? For example I wrote research paper and teaching material at my company or uni research project papers etc. Are these eligible?

I am asking because I don't want to put something in my resume that might make me look like a fraud (because of unknowing).

Comment: "Is it valid to state publications which exist, but are not publicly downloadable." Yes, but they have to be actually published (by a journal or conference) even if access is restricted (typically payment is needed). I'm not in CS, but I don't think internal documents from your company count (although you can certainly mention such experience).

Comment: Ah OK, if it actually has to be published I probably have to scrape all of them, besides of the peer-reviewed conference ones. I just wanted to somehow emphasize in my resume that I am willing and able to write academic paper (also in regard of TA/RA positions)

Comment: If I told you that I have written a great treatise, but you cannot read and check it, would you hire me? It would probably be better if a reference mentioned such things in your LOR.

Comment: Of course I see your point, but I could provide them the documents. Isn't it the same with research projects that I am mentioning in my resume. How should the admission committee actually check that I did what I am claiming (don't get a wrong impression; I did everything I'm stating :))?

Comment: My LoR actually do, so should I still keep it in the resume or is it enough if the letter state it?

Comment: It's enough for the letter to state it.

Comment: I think you are confusing an academic CV that an applicant to, say, a tenure track position would submit with a simple CV that an applicant to a master's program would submit.  Keep it short, sweet and strong.  We want the admissions committee to be able to read the great things you've done, without exerting themselves to sort out what was what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of publications that you should list in the publications section of an academic CV are those writings that contain technical work at the level of a typical scientific publication.  This can include non-peer-reviewed and unpublished works, but they should be the sort of thing that, if circumstances were different, might be reasonable to send through peer-review.

With regards to the examples that you list, then:

- Confidential company research paper: this would be reasonable to put in a non-peer-reviewed research section, with a note that it is not available due to confidentiality restrictions.
- Company teaching materials: these would go in "teaching experience," not publications.
- University research project papers: these would generally not be listed, unless something above and beyond the usual happened, like they were actually sent off for peer reviewed publication.

Comment: I wish I had read this answer two decades ago (of course, it's not possible). I had an opportunity to enter (re-enter?) a PhD program during my industry career. I was unable to come up with a list of publications (although I had quite a few company confidential papers), I had to give up the opportunity. Sigh.